# exec() при работе в Yii2 возвращает пустой массив

Tags: php, yii2, exec

Предполагаю, что проблема при указании окружения, либо в правах выполнения скрипта.

```
exec ( "swetest -edir$sweph -b$utdatenow -ut$utnow -p0123456789DAttt -eswe -house$longitude,$latitude,$this->h_sys -flsj -g, -head", $out);
```

Сама библиотека "swetest" лежит в @web/sweph/

Пути такие (сразу оговорюсь, что пробовал и абсолютные пути и относительные):

```
$swephsrc = \Yii::getAlias('@webroot'). '/sweph';
```

Окружение указываю так:

```
$PATH = getenv('PATH'); 
putenv("PATH=$PATH:$swephsrc");
```

Как итог, $out -результат выполнения exec() возвращает пустой массив. В логах апача:

```
sh: 1: swetest: not found
```

Соответственно, если я укажу абсолютный путь до swetest сразу при выполнении exec, то массив все равно пустой, а в логах апача:

```
sh: 1: /var/www/html/web/sweph/swetest: not found
```

Скрипт выполняется от Пользователя www-data, доступы (chown) к данному файлу и всей директории выставлял для этого юзера.

Пробовал вынести данный файл повыше, в корень самого приложения yii2, или например, в /web/assets.

В общем, с доступами по разному игрался, мне кажется перерыл весь Интернет :)

Не особо силен в настройке окружения, но в доке к данной библиотеке (а суть работы swetest - это результат работы швейцарских эфемерид) написано, что PATH необходимо настраивать именно так:

1. Вся директория /sweph/ лежит в корне приложения
2. Пути указаны так
   $swephsrc = 'sweph';
   putenv("PATH=$PATH:$swephsrc");

Т.к. у меня DocumentRoot смотрит в директорию /web приложения Yii2, то я и сложил /sweph в директорию /web.

P.S. проверял на наличие safe_mode (использую последние версии php, а там они отсутствуют), также исключил все функции из disable_functions в настройках php.ini.
Пробовал на версиях php 5.5, 5.6 и 7
Проблема везде одна:

```
sh: 1: swetest: not found
```

Пишите, буду раз Вашим комментариям и советам, спасибо!

Comment: попробуйте запустить через exec что-то стандратное, вроде ls или whoami, может станет яснее, что нужно гуглить

Comment: Да, запускал и ls и whoami отрабатывает. Я предполагаю, что наверно файл swetest необходимо положить в какую-то директорию, из который скрипт его увидит и нормально отработает, но в какую?) . 80-ый порт смотрит на директорию @web

Comment: да вроде нет, если до файла и всех директорий по пути есть соотв. права доступа и запуск идет через абсолютный путь - ни в какое специфическое место бинарник класть не требуется

Comment: Самое интересное, я у себя на компьютере поднял локал - и у меня и с абсолютными путями и с относительными работает. А вот на сервере удаленном попробовал и на simplecloud и на digitalocean - ошибка. Причем окружение на сервере делаю такое же и у меня локально на компе (разница лишь в том, что у меня на ноуте Ubuntu Desktop, а на сервере Server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После нескольких бессонных ночей ответ был найден:

```
apt-get install lib32z1
```

Именно этой библиотеки не хватало. На одном из форумов увидел рекомендацию
установить ia32-libs
Но моя система (ubuntu server 14.04) ответила:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
```

Но мне оказалось достаточно из рекомендованных установить lib32z1.
Пошел читать мануалы про данную библиотеку, зачем она и почему меня так долго мучила :)

Возможно кому-то данная информация пригодится, а может кто-то уже знает что эта за либа и напишет, буду очень благодарен